# Replacing some series of words with other words

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as Follows

```
String sentence = "I tried to speak @td Spanish @ty, and my @yd friend tried to @yi speak English @yy.";
```

I want to replace @td, @ty, @yi.. etc words by empty space('').
@xx words are dynamic, keeps changing in different scenarios.

How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: So to be clear: you want to replace words that are preceded by @?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String sentence = "I tried to speak @td Spanish @ty, and my @yd friend tried to @yi speak English @yy.";

        sentence = sentence.replaceAll(" \\@[a-z]+", "");

        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain Why "\\" and "+" is required in - replaceAll(" \\@[a-z]+", "")

Thanks

Comment: @PRATHAPS `@` is a special character in Regular Expressions. So for the regex parser to take it as a literal `@` you will need to put a back slash before `@`. The thing is, \ is also a special character in Java. So for Java to take the \ literally you need another \ before it. Thus the `\\@` at the beginning. The `[a-z]+` in regex means "one or more instances of `[a-z]` (any small letter).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sentence.replaceAll("@[A-za-z]+","");
```

The regex `@[A-za-z]+` will look for all words composed of letters only, starting with the @ symbol, and having at least 1 letter.

Alternatively, if it is guaranteed that the words are at least 2 letters long, you can use the regex `@[A-za-z]{2,}`, and if they will be exactly 2 letters long, then `@[A-za-z]{2}`.

Comment: Exactly!! this code will work fine for 2 letters preceding to "@"
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is `/\s@.+?\b/g`. Then replace the matches with empty string.

This matches any words starting with `@`

See http://regexr.com/38v6d